# How to use DropDownListFor when model is List

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

My model is a generic List. I want to use DropDownList for foreign key property binding.
My code is

Model

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int NationalityId { get; set; }
}

public class Nationality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var nationalities = new List<Nationality>
    {
        new Nationality{Id = 0, Name = "CHOOSE NATIONALITY..."},
        new Nationality{Id = 1, Name = "POLAND"},
        new Nationality{Id = 2, Name = "USA"},
        new Nationality{Id = 3, Name = "CANADA"}
    };


    var Nationalities = new SelectList(nationalities, "Id", "Name");


    var persons = new List<PersonViewModel>
    {
        new PersonViewModel{Id = 1, LastName = "KOWALSKI", NationalityId = 1},
        new PersonViewModel{Id = 1, LastName = "SMITH", NationalityId = 2},
        new PersonViewModel{Id = 1, LastName = "SCHERBATSKY", NationalityId = 3}
    };

    ViewBag.Nationalities = Nationalities;

    return View(persons);
}
```

View

```
@model List<PersonViewModel>

@Html.EditorFor(m=> Model[0].LastName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[0].NationalityId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Nationalities)

@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[1].LastName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[1].NationalityId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Nationalities)

@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[2].LastName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[2].NationalityId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Nationalities)
```

Anyone can tell me why NationalityId property is not bound well

I can't upload image but it's not binding at all. Every DropDownList has 'CHOOSE NATIONALITY...' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using Editor templates:
First - create view `Shared\EditorTemplates\PersonViewModel.cshtml` containing:

```
@model PersonViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.LastName) 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.NationalityId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Nationalities)
```

And in your current view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     @Html.EditorFor(x => Model[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view model to this

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int NationalityId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Nationality> Nationalities {get;set;}
}
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var nationalities = new List<Nationality>
    {
        new Nationality{Id = 0, Name = "CHOOSE NATIONALITY..."},
        new Nationality{Id = 1, Name = "POLAND"},
        new Nationality{Id = 2, Name = "USA"},
        new Nationality{Id = 3, Name = "CANADA"}
    };


    var nationalities = new SelectList(nationalities, "Id", "Name");


    var persons = new List<PersonViewModel>
    {
        new PersonViewModel{Id = 1, LastName = "KOWALSKI", NationalityId = 1 , Nationalities = nationalities},
        new PersonViewModel{Id = 1, LastName = "SMITH", NationalityId = 2, Nationalities = nationalities},
        new PersonViewModel{Id = 1, LastName = "SCHERBATSKY", NationalityId = 3, Nationalities = nationalities}
    };    
    return View(persons);
}
```

And in your view

```
@model List<PersonViewModel>

@Html.EditorFor(m => m[0].LastName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[0].NationalityId, Model[0].Nationalities)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m[1].LastName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[1].NationalityId, Model[1].Nationalities)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m[2].LastName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[2].NationalityId, Model[2].Nationalities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Each dropdown needs its own select list. Currently you are using the same select list for each dropdown.
2. You need to specify a selected value for each select list, like so:

   ```
   new SelectList(nationalities, "Id", "Name", persons[0].NationalityId);
   ```